# What's the maximum number of train phrases for each intent in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

What's the maximum number of train phases for each intent in dialogflow?
I know there have max intent number 2000 for one agent. but what's the number of the train phrases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have 2000 training phrases per intent.

Answer (score 0):

As Taylor has pointed out, the number of Training Phrases per intent is limited to 2000.

For more such limits and quotas of Dialogflow, you can refer https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/agent-limits-and-quotas